# How to Deal with Hyphens Elasticsearch QueryBuilder Java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to do back end filtering for a table of data that I have for the user. Column filtering is available in the UI and I need to be able to query the Elasticsearch database on field name by substring.

`QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery(field.get(i),String.format("*%s*",filter.get(i).toLowerCase())));`

This is the query I've tried and also tried adding the .operator(Operator.AND), but it says QueryBuilder doesn't have operator function.

Currently, this query works through a POST request to the database, but I need to be able to do this through the Java API.

```
{
    "query":{
        "simple_query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["ideaId"], 
            "query" : "*hello-world*", 
            "analyze_wildcard":true, 
            "default_operator":"AND"
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried replacing the hyphen with an AND, but doesn't return the correct record.

```
{
    "query":{
        "simple_query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["ideaId"], 
            "query" : "*hello AND world*", 
            "analyze_wildcard":true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering you must use simpleQueryStringQuery:

```
QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(String.format("*%s*", filter.get(i).toLowerCase()))
                .analyzeWildcard(true)
                .field(field.get(i))
                .defaultOperator(Operator.AND))
```